# SQL Query - Order by in Union (order by when entered)

Tags: sql, union

Example of what I have:

```
SELECT [thing] FROM [A]
UNION ALL
SELECT [thing] FROM [B]
UNION ALL
SELECT [thing] FROM [C]
UNION ALL
SELECT [thing] FROM [D]
UNION ALL 
SELECT [thing] FROM [E]
```

In my union I want *thing* to be sorted by oldest to newest entry date. So, if I add a value to my thing field from table A today I want to see that value get sorted to the bottom of my column in my union query.  Is there a way to do this by using Order By?

Comment: it depends on whether you are maintaining an `entry_date` column of some sort in all the tables that are part of your query.  If you don't have that column defined, then no, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

`select` the date column from the tables in `union all` and use it to `order` the `thing` column. This is because you can't use `order by` when using `union`. It can only be specified at the end of all queries.

```
select thing from
(
SELECT [thing],[datecolumn] as dt FROM [A]
UNION ALL
SELECT [thing],[datecolumn] FROM [B]
UNION ALL
SELECT [thing],[datecolumn] FROM [C]
UNION ALL
SELECT [thing],[datecolumn] FROM [D]
UNION ALL 
SELECT [thing],[datecolumn] FROM [E]
) t
order by dt
```

Comment: I am sorry for bothering you, but can you take a look at a similar question i have? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303336/select-top-with-multiple-union-and-with-order-by